# reconfiguring the model with the use of at least two breeds

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

so what i want to do is to reconfigure the model with the use of at least two breeds and than try to change the breed while the simulation is running.
many thanks .

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  create-turtles nBugs [set color red set size 2]
end

to go
 tick
 if ticks >= nCycles [stop]
 foreach sort turtles
  [ ?1 ->
    ask ?1

      [ set xcor xcor + random 3 - 1
        set ycor ycor + random 3 - 1

        if random-float 1 < 0.1 [set size size + 0.5]
        ifelse ycor <= 0 [set color yellow]
                         [set color blue]


        type "I'm agent " type who type " and I'm in " type xcor type ", " print ycor
      ]
  ] ;comment IF using simple ask

end
```

Comment: what do you want the two breeds to do? What do they represent? What behaviours do they have that are different from each other? Also, you only need `foreach` when using lists and you only need lists for very specific purposes where it is important to know the order or to have the same item appear twice. In this case, I suspect you really want to `ask turtles [ ]` to do the randomised colour and size.

Comment: it's basically the main idea , yes .

Answer (score 1):

If you're only asking about how to change the breed during run-time, you can just assign the breed variable to the new breed.

```
ask turtle 0 [ set breed some-other-breed]
```